# updating a useState to the value that it's already holding inside of a custom React hook causes infinite re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-component

```
function useHandleURL(mode, page) {
  const [is_page_hidden, set_is_page_hidden] = useState(true);

  ...

  set_is_page_hidden(true);
}
```

The above will cause an infinite re-render.

I had to solve by doing this:

```
function useHandleURL(mode, page) {
  const [is_page_hidden, set_is_page_hidden] = useState(true);

  ...

  if (!is_page_hidden) {
    set_is_page_hidden(true);
  }
}
```

This is not the behavior inside of React components. Inside a component, if I set a useState to `true` when it is already `true`, then it will not cause re-render.

Can someone confirm this behavior and explain why it causes infinite re-render inside of a Hook but not a Component?

Comment: I cannot confirm this.. I see an infinite loop in both scenarios, which is what I expected. Can you show the exact code you're using within the component that *doesn't* create an infinite loop?

Comment: I *can* confirm that using the same exact code within the body of a function component render loops the same as when it's in a custom hook. The issue is the unconditional calling of the state setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *can* confirm that using the same exact code within the body of a function component render loops the same as when it's in a custom hook. The issue is the unconditional calling of the state setter.

See `useState` [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the [Object.is comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)
>
> ***Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out.*** That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with `useMemo`.

Also note that "React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out." means running the render function one more time, not "render to the DOM one more time", so any unexpected side-effects, like enqueueing another state update are problematic. The ***entire*** function body of a function component ***is*** the render function.

Consider the following code though:

```js
function App() {
  const [is_page_hidden, set_is_page_hidden] = React.useState(true);

  const handler = () => set_is_page_hidden(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("RENDERED!");
  });
  
  return <button type="button" onClick={handler}>Click</button>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

We're conditionally enqueueing state updates with the same value and notice that no rerenders are triggered as measured by the `useEffect` hook logging 1 effect per 1 render cycle.

## Conclusion

Conditionally enqueueing the state update is correct.

```
function useHandleURL(mode, page) {
  const [is_page_hidden, set_is_page_hidden] = useState(true);

  ...

  if (!is_page_hidden) {
    set_is_page_hidden(true);
  }
}
```

### Update

I just realized that it's not necessarily the unconditional state update, but more the unintentional side-effect.

- Render loops

  ```
   function App() {
     const [is_page_hidden, set_is_page_hidden] = React.useState(true);

     set_is_page_hidden(true);

     return ...;
   }
  ```
- Stable, no render looping

  ```js
      function App() {
        const [is_page_hidden, set_is_page_hidden] = React.useState(true);

        React.useEffect(() => {
          console.log("RENDERED!");
          set_is_page_hidden(true);
        });
    
        return "Stackoverflow is awesome.";
      }

      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
      ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        rootElement
      );
  ```

  ```html
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
      <div id="root" />
  ```

In the stable version the state update is an intentional state update as an intentional side-effect, so no rerenders are triggered since the state value is the same as the previous render cycle.